# Subtracting value to file name suffix and bulk rename

Tags: file, unix, rename

silly question, is there a **UNIX** command to rename files from the format:

> "particles_00090.png" "particles_00091.png" .... "particles_00131.png"

to

> "particles-00000.png" "particles-00001.png" .... "particles-00041.png"

Basically, I'd like to subtract the value **90** to the file suffix whilst keeping the number of numeric values (in the case above we have 5 zeroes) and convert underscore to dashes.

Comment: Are you wondering about a simple rename, changing the 9 to a 0, or subtracting 90 from the number on the end?

Comment: Subtracting 90 to the number at the end..

Comment: I don't know of any super simple command that does this, but you could always write a script to do it.

Comment: I am a bit stuck with the "subtract" value step.. any idea?

Comment: Since scripts treat everything as strings, and convert to integers when needed, you could use `cut` to split the filename on '_', then split the second half on '.' to get the number, then simply subtract 90. To get the same number of zeros would probably take a loop of sorts to add zeros, then just tack on the new number. Then you want to use `cut` to get the "particles" part and ".png" part, and concatenate everything together.... I think

Comment: I believe you mean "particles_00000.png" and "particles_00001.png", correct?

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can script the algorithm:

```
for fn_orig in particles_*
do
    # split the file name up into 3 parts
    extension="${fn_orig##*.}"
    filename="${fn_orig%.*}"
    number="${filename#particles_}"

    # do the desired math
    subtract=$(expr $number + 0 - 90 )

    # reassemble to the desired format
    fn_new=$(printf "particles-%05d.%s" $subtract $extension)

    # output the command, in case tweaking is wanted
    # just remove the echo to actually do it
    echo mv "$fn_orig" "$fn_new"
done
```

Sample run:

```
$ ls
particles_00090.png  particles_00091.png  particles_00131.png  command.sh

$ ./command.sh
mv particles_00090.png particles-00000.png
mv particles_00091.png particles-00001.png
mv particles_00131.png particles-00041.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's something not very nice and scalable, but that works in *bash* (it does it in 2 steps: files that require last 2 digits to be replaced and the ones that require last 3 digits):

```
for f in {90..99}; do mv particles_000$f particles_000$((f-90)) ; done
for f in {100..131}; do mv particles_00$f particles_00$((f-90)) ; done
```

Comment: Clever use of range expansion.

Comment: Thanks, but by far not as elaborate as your solution.